# JTable - dynamic

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to set up a JTable.
It seems to my I have to now beforehand How many objects I put into my Row. 
Now, is there a way to have a number of objects that is slightly too large, thereby inducing the table to simply leave blank space?a

If any one is still interested, this was my code:

```
 int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< data.size(); i++){
        LinkedList tmp = (LinkedList) data.get(i);
        if (t<tmp.size()){
            t = tmp.size();
        }
    }

    Object [][] o = new Object[names.size()][t];

    JTable table = new JTable (data, names);
    this.add(table);
```

Comment: Which one? I am trying several ways to set up some kind of tabular

Comment: The Problem is, I need a table which can change Size, and I just wonder if that is even possible in Java?

Comment: feel free to show all codes you tried. Without codes, we can't help

Comment: I looked at a tutorial and it seems that even though the table displays rows, it gives headlines to the columns! what sense does that make? Seriously all I want is to display a .csv on a JPanel. And no, I have no working code, because I have simply no idea how to convert my rows into columns that apparently are no real columns either. None of what I tried seems to make sense, I am seriously considering just looping over JLabels, at least they display what I want them to.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645948/java-console-output-in-jtable/18646292#18646292

Answer (score 3):

Use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)::[addRow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.util.Vector%29).
The table's size can be changed dynamically in this way. Don't forget to set your model with `JTable::setModel(TableModel);` or by using an appropriate constructor.

Comment: I do not want to change an actually existing table. The Idea is, I have a list of lists (the inner lists containing strings) and want a Jtable with the lists. Now, using that "object  [][]" the constructor needs which I never saw befor, I guess the dimension would be outerlist.size() * x. Only, I have no idea what the x could be.

Comment: Also, is there any way to make a table with columns instead of rows?

Comment: @newnewbie Instead of having a list of list. Have list of objects where each object is of type CustonClass(your custom defined class).