# Loop with NetApp API-Runner

Tags: java, arrays, loops, volumes, netapp

Big Picture: I created two Java-Classes, one to get Output from a NetApp Simulator and another to create a JTable with Volume names and specifications.

The Code for the JTable is "exactly" this one:
[Java: Console output in JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645948/java-console-output-in-jtable)

Sample Code to get the Volume names:

```
public static Object VolName() {

    ApiRunner runner = new ApiRunner(ApiTarget.builder()

    .withHost(host).withUserName(user).withPassword(pass)
            .withTargetType(TargetType.FILER).useHttp().build());

    VolumeListInfoIterStartRequest volListReq = new VolumeListInfoIterStartRequest();

    Iterator<VolumeInfo> volumeIter = runner.iterate(volListReq, 20);

    VolumeInfo volume = null;
    while(volumeIter.hasNext()) {
        volume = volumeIter.next();
        System.out.println("Sample 1: " + volume.getName());

    }
    System.out.println("Sample 2: " + volume.getName());
    return volume.getName();

}
```

The Java-Commands which are from a NetApp Java Library.

Now to explain the Problem the Console output:

```
Sample 1: volume1
Sample 1: volume2
Sample 1: volume3
Sample 1: volume4
Sample 1: volume5
Sample 2: volume5
```

My return value is always volume5. How do I create an array out of this method or another method to loop this values?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer (or, if you think it won't be helpful to anyone else, delete the question).